# SQL get min id then get next min compared to previous

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table that has contents about items with ids and dates. I want get Id's from the table in order from MIN to MAX, the problem is that the Id's are fetched from the table based on date, ex:

Table with the items...

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |

And the result when searching with date at 1, would be something like this:

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

This has to work as stored procedure, because I'm calling this procedure from PLC, so I'm giving comparing value from there, ex: I know ID 2 and I would give 2 as comparator to search next min ID from the table.

So far the procedure looks like this:

```
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getProdIDdata]

@sentID         INT,

@firstID        INT OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
SELECT @firstID = ISNULL(MIN(product_id),0) FROM productsSeries 
WHERE @sentID < (SELECT MIN(product_id) FROM productsSeries) AND deleted = 0
END
```

Thanks in advance.

-Toni

Comment: My table https://imgur.com/a/9MN5dn3

Answer (score 0):

> I want get Id's from the table in order from MIN to MAX, the problem is that the Id's are fetched from the table based on date

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
select id, date
from mytable
where date = 1
order by id
```

Comment: No that doesn't do what I want, I want to get Id's from table 1 per time, and at every query I would get the next min Id number from the table, ex. Table has Id's 1 to 8 and Id's 1, 3, 7 are inside set dates, so I would get them in this order. This is to avoid running the procedure too much, since I'm calling it from PLC.